# Jquery .Click Function is Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I'm working on a K-Mapping application for Electrical Engineering. However, I'm stuck on a single click function.

```
if(jQuery)
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
        alert("Evaluate Click Works");
        var match = $(mintermIndexes).compare(ArrayOfEight);
        if(match){
            alert("All squares have been checked");
        }   
        return false;
});
});
```

This is HTML,

```
  <div id="body">

        <input id="Clear" value="Clear Form" type="submit" />
        <a id="Evaluate" href="#" >Evaluate</a>

    </div>
```

I really could use some help, I did share the only code that I think there is a problem. Please share your thoughts on how to fix this issue. Thanks.

p.s : I tried almost every possible selector, but still nothing. There is no respond when i hit the link.

EDIT: Changing the referencing order in the head tag worked, i.e i changed the order of my jquery app and jquery reference order. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Have you tried eliminating the if(jQuery) line?

Comment: The alert triggers here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Ls4yK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always encounter this problem.
My solution is to put the script below the tag I want to manage.
like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
       <input id="Clear" value="Clear Form" type="submit" />
       <a id="Evaluate" href="#" >Evaluate</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a').click(function(){
           alert("Evaluate Click Works");
           var match = $(mintermIndexes).compare(ArrayOfEight);
           if(match){
               alert("All squares have been checked");
       }   
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

explanation:

you need to make sure that the "tag" is loaded first

Answer (score 3):

Works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/wCRLE/

Try removing the `if (jQuery)`

Also, have you correctly referenced the `jQuery` scripts?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: It does not work in my document though, im gonna try to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
       alert("Evaluate Click Works");
       var match = $(mintermIndexes).compare(ArrayOfEight);
       if(match){
           alert("All squares have been checked");
       }   
       return false;
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="body">
       <input id="Clear" value="Clear Form" type="submit" />
       <a id="Evaluate" href="#" >Evaluate</a>

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No problem here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5Yttd/

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the if(JQuery)

Also, make sure you are loading JQuery before you load your content scripts. If you don't, nothing will happen.